# Android playing Audio Files

Tags: android

I have an intent that launches an Audio Player Intent, and plays an Audio File. The Audio Player offcourse is external to my application. When the user presses the back button, my activity is again displayed to the user. I want the Audio Player to close when the user presses the back button. How can i control this.

Comment: Audio Player will close by default when you're hitting the back button, and your activity will display since it was the previous activity in the stack. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed this code on the `OnResume()` of my calling activity and it works like a GEM.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    
if (mAudioManager.isMusicActive()) 
{

     Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
     i.putExtra("command", "pause");
     this.sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two options to achieve your requirement

1. call "finish()" after startActivity() which is used to start audioplayer. finish() function will close your application and when user press back button from audioplayer, Android will display previous activity most probably home screen.
2. User CLEAR_TOP flag when you start the activity. Clear top flag will clear all top activity so when user press back from audio player, Android OS will display Home Screen.

   Intent i = new Intent(......);

   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

   startActivity(i);

Thank You

Comment: But when the user presses the back button on the Audio Player, The player closes and my activity is displayed. But the Audio Keeps on playing for some reason. Is this a Phone Specific Problem, or the expected result. For both cases i want to stop the audio playing when the user comes back onto my screen.

Comment: Hello, It is default behavior of Audio Player when you press back it will keep running in background.

Comment: So i want it to stop Playing. Any ideas how this can be achieved ?